# Easiest way to convert array into xml string?

Tags: php

So I'm trying to convert an array to an XML document (just outputting it as a string). I know php has `json_encode` built in and it works fine, but I can't seem to find any good XML equivalents.

Basically, the array is the result of a `PDOStatement->fetchAll();`

I'd like the output to look like this:

```
<arrayitem>
   <iteminfo1>text</iteminfo1>
   <iteminfo2>text</iteminfo2>
   <iteminfo3>text</iteminfo3>
   <iteminfo4>text</iteminfo4>
   <iteminfo5>text</iteminfo5>
</arrayitem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken straight off of [PHP: SimpleXML - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

```
function array2XML($arr,$root) { 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><{$root}></{$root}>");
$f = create_function('$f,$c,$a',' 
    foreach($a as $v) { 
        if(isset($v["@text"])) { 
            $ch = $c->addChild($v["@tag"],$v["@text"]); 
        } else { 
            $ch = $c->addChild($v["@tag"]); 
            if(isset($v["@items"])) { 
                $f($f,$ch,$v["@items"]); 
            } 
        } 
        if(isset($v["@attr"])) { 
            foreach($v["@attr"] as $attr => $val) { 
                $ch->addAttribute($attr,$val); 
            } 
        } 
    }'); 
$f($f,$xml,$arr); 
return $xml->asXML(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in tools to do that, but it is easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in library that can help you do this, but not as simple as json_encode.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php